# Android compose cope with windows insets for tablets and phones

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am having issues with coping with windows insets in my current Android Jetpack Compose project.

When I install my application on a phone the padding is fine and all my compose screens display all their content fine.

However when I install the same application on my Samsung tablet (which has a software bottom navigation strip) all my applications screens have the bottom content hidden.

I have been able to fix on tablet by using windows insets however fix is also affecting the application on my phone.

How can i detect when to "fix" the windows insets for this situation and any others that i have not encountered yet?

How can I detect/react to the location of all windows insets on any device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [Scaffold](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/material#scaffold) in your composables. Even if you don't need any of it's modules, it provides a `ContentPadding` variable showing you the insets that should be used:

```
Scaffold(/* ... */) { contentPadding ->
    // Screen content
    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(contentPadding)) { /* ... */ }
}
```

You can then pass that content padding to your container composable as a `Modifier.padding()`

Comment: It seems like a general best practice is "If you use a Scaffold, then you should have top level container (like Box) whose padding is dedicated to the scaffold padding". If you try to use an existing top level container that already has padding then it seems you cannot share the same .padding() function without a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this

```
setContent {
    Box(Modifier.safeDrawingPadding()) {
        // the rest of the app
    }
}
```

read the doc from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets#compose-apis)